# How do I include Project Properties without the large .vs folder in GitHub repository?

Tags: visual-studio, github

How can I include my Visual Studio projects properties, i.e. the inlcude directories etc., when commiting to my GitHub repository. I have figured out that the properties are saved in the hidden folder ".vs" in the project directory, but that folder grows several gigabytes large for reasons I don't know. Is there a way to limit the size of this folder or to only include the necessary subdirectories of .vs? And if the latter, what are the necessary subdirectories?

Comment: “I have figured out that the properties are saved in the hidden folder ".vs" in the project directory”, so what exactly did you figure out? `.vs` can contain many things, and not everything is "the projects properties" and you can exclude some.

Answer (score 1):

You can add:`.vs/`to the .gitignore file so that the folder will not be included in the repository.
If you already committed it to GIT, run `git rm .vs` in addition to adding it to the ignore list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it seems that the project properties are saved in that directory, and without those all the additional include directories aren't included when commiting. I found that the large size of the .vs folder comes from the ipch subdirectory, and this is the one I wan't to remove from my repository.

Comment: You dont need that folder. It has a dot as a name prefix because it is unneeded as a source to keep in git

Answer (score 0):

The project properties are saved in the *.*proj and *.sln files, not in the .vs directory.
For information, visual studio can create the .gitignore by itself and it will add 
`.vs/` to the ignore list